# date formatting from yyyy-m-d to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, sql

I am getting date from a calendar using the code

```
if ($_POST){
    $m = $_POST['m'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];

$event_date = $y."-".$m."-".$d;
```

the date is of the format yyyy-m-d how can i change the format to yyyy-mm-dd so i can insert into database

Comment: How is the user inputting the values?

Comment: "the date is of the format yyyy-m-d" even for 2012-08-31? How does that work?

Comment: Are you sure month & date is 1 digit each?

Comment: when we ask you to do research in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice we **really** mean it. Look at the Related Section to the right please and find your solution there.

Comment: and what database are you using that you cannot insert the date as `yyyy-m-d`?

Answer (score 5):

```
$time = strtotime( $event_date );
$myDate = date( 'Y-m-d', $time );
```

First line converts to timestamp.
Second line converts to date format you'd like

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be by using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) combined with [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
$event_date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it before you use it like this:

```
if($_POST['m']<10)
{
    $m='0'.$_POST['m'];
}
else
{
    $m=$_POST['m'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST){
    $m = $_POST['m'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];

if($m<10)
{
  $m="0".$m;
}
if($d<10)
{
  $d="0".$d;
}
$event_date = $y."-".$m."-".$d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like `substr("00" . $m, -2)` work?

Don't use PHP so syntax might be wrong, but the approach should be obvious, add 00 to the beginning then take the last 2 chars

Answer (score 0):

You can use strftime and perform a check using checkdate:

```
if ($_POST){

  $m = $_POST['m'];
  $d = $_POST['d'];
  $y = $_POST['y'];

  $event_date = checkdate($m, $d, $y) ? strftime('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y)) : null;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($event_date)));
```